# SQL Server, Oracle8i syntax

Tags: sql

I am running the simple query below

```
select  '''' + event_number + '''' +',' as Event_N
from mytable
```

which gives:

```
Event_N
---------------
'BAB0910000001',
'CDD0910000002',
'ODB0910000002',
'YDB0910000003',
'NYC0910000004',
```

Question 1: Is there a way in SQL that can show the result as:

```
Event_N
'BAB0910000001','CDD0910000002','ODB0910000002','YDB0910000003','NYC0910000004',
```

I could do a dirty step by pressing Delte and End but would not be efficient when more than 100 records.

I am using Aqua Data Studio 7.5.34 and the back end is MS SQL Server 2000/5/8.

Event_number data type is `varchar`.

Question 2: But when I tried to run this query, it showed me the error below. Could someone please help!!!

```
select  '''' + event_key + '''' +',' as Event_K
from mytable
```

I am using Aqua Data Studio 7.5.34 and the back end is MS SQL Server 2000/5/8.

--event_key data type is int.

> [Error] Script lines: 1-3 --------------------------
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ''' to data type int.
>   Msg: 245, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

---

I ran the following query, which gives:

```
select ''''||EVENT_KEY||'''' as Event_K
from mytable

EVENT_K
'28732033'
'28797708'
'28796943'
'28133100'
'28718239'
```

Question 3: Is there a way in SQL that could add a comma (,) to the end of these records and output the result similar to question 1?

I am using Aqua Data Studio 7.5.34 and the back end is oracle 8i

Comment: Erm. @KMan -- I think you may have edited out the actual problem when you reformatted that script. I believe the all-on-one-line result is actually what @Tom wants to produce, as opposed to the line-by-line format you've edited it into. As it stands now, the only difference between the current and desired results is the line of hyphens you've added, from what I can see...

Comment: Reformatted Question 1 requested output, to show required format.

Comment: @Matt: My bad! It gets quite challenging to understand *large* questions without formatting.

Comment: @KMan Hey, no worries. I just didn't have enough reputation to edit it back :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1 and 3 - essentially the same as this question: [Use SQL instead of Delete and End from keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029129/use-sql-instead-of-delete-and-end-from-keyboard)

OMG Ponies' post includes links to a selection of techniques in Oracle, as well as SQLServer.

Question 2 requires an explicit CAST or CONVERT on the event_key, to change it into character instead of numeric data - like so:

```
select  '''' + convert(varchar,event_key) + '''' +',' as Event_K
from mytable
```